# How to define type for children that can accept a ref?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a higher-order component called `Tooltip` that accepts a child and attaches a ref to it.
So the child has to be either a `JSXIntrensic Element` or a `forwardRef` component. How do I type the children prop?

```html
<Tooltip>
  <Child/> <!-- NO fragment/mulitpleChildren/component that can not take a ref -->
</Tooltip>
```

```js
type Props = {
  children: ReactElement // what is the correct type here?
}
function Tooltip(props:Props){
  const element = Children.only(props.children)

  // clone the child and attach a ref to it,
  // by preserving any ref it already has.
 
  const clone = cloneElement(element, {
        ...element.props,
        ref: (el: HTMLElement) => {
          setTargetEl(el)  
          if (element.ref) { // Property 'ref' does not exist on type ReactElement<any,string|JSXElementConstructor<any>>
            if (typeof element.ref === "function") {
              element.ref(el)
            } else {
              element.ref.current = el
            }
          }
        },
      })
   
   return (
           //something
          )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try with the DOMElement interface but it needs 2 type args, I don't know if any would do for your case.

```
type Props = {
  children: DOMElement<any,any>
}
```